# Infinite for loops are apparently tricky.

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

Here I am once again. This is apparently the only way I know how to learn. What I am doing is making a for loop. Yes. Something so simple. Yet, I "*have*" a problem with them. More or less a problem with infinite loops. What I need to do is make a loop that counts down from 10...0. It seems easy for some of you. Yes I am very aware. I am nothing more than a student learning.

This is the code that I have:

```
       for (var i = 11; i >= 1; i++) {
    console.log(i);
    }
```

I am stuck at this point. All that it does is crash my browser every time. Help is greatly appreciated. I would like a *thorough* explanation of what I am doing wrong, what I should do, and why I might have made this harder than it needed to be. Thank you!

Comment: so why exactly are you incrementing i? and isn't it always greater than 1?

Comment: What do you mean? Oh at the end? i++?

Comment: if you start at 11 and you are using i++, then you tell me when will it stop?  You want it to loop while i >= 1.  When will i >= 1 be not true in your case.

Comment: Nevermind. I got it. I figured it out. I should have had i = 10; i >= 0; i--

Comment: I like how that was one of the answers and then you said you figured it out with a nevermind.

Comment: I didn't see the answers because I didn't refresh the page. But I should have seen that on my own. I guess you can't debug stupidity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everyone learns differently! In this case, you're asking the code to increment (aka add) with the `++` syntax. So, if `i = 1`, after `i++` `i = 2`. Similarly `i--` decrements (aka subtracts) from `i`.

Now, the first two parts of the loop check the value of `i` and continue the operation. In your case, you're asking the program `set i equal to 10. If i is greater than 1, add 1 to it.` That's where you're getting the infinite loop because `i` will always be greater than 1. What you want is. `for (var i = 10; i >= 0; i--) {//code here};`

You could also check out `while` and `do/while` loops.

Comment: I don't see how this loop is checking to see if i is greater than 11. This is an error.

Comment: You're right. Sorry. I changed it so it decrements from 10 -> 0.

Comment: Wasn't referring to that.  you say "If i is greater than 11"

Comment: Oh. I just meant that the `i >= 11 (ok now 10)` part of the code is checking the value of `i` and either continuing with the loop or leaving it. I felt that since the OP is struggling they might benefit from a non-technical explanation of the syntax.

Comment: I know,  I'm just saying that no where in the loop is it checking if it's greater than 11.  It's checking if its >= 1.  Or in the new case >= 0.  If i was 10 in the OP code it would still add 1.  Being greater than 11 plays no role

Comment: You're absolutely right. Thanks for the clarification! I fixed the answer.

Answer (score 1):

For a loop to run from `10` to `0` iterator `i` should be decrementing in each iteration. But you are incrementing it instead so `for loop` never terminates.

```js
for (var i = 10; i>=0; i--) {
  console.log(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Variable i starts at 11, and is then incremented by one each loop. Since the condition is that i >= 1, it never ends. You need to change it so that i decrements by one each loop, like this:

```
for (var i= 11; i>=1; i--){
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to learn difference between increments and decrements.
increments mean to add specific value to your variable
while on other hand decrements means to reduce the value of your variable by some specific number.

Now in your case `i++` means you are adding `1` to your variable `i` with every iteration of loop, while to end your loop you have set the condition to `i>=1`

this results in an infinite loop which crashes your browser, as `i` would never be equal to `1` or `i>=1` will never be true as with each iteration the value of `i` increased by `1` number, so it would continue execution, until your browser crashes.

What you are looking for is:

```
for (var i = 10; i >= 0; i--) {   
     console.log(i);
}
```

now `i` will start from `10`
 and will gradually reduce to `0` and your loop will end.

Hope it explained.